# EF Core tables not created

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am working on a personal project using ef core with SQLLite as my underlying TB for now, I am having an issue where A) Some of the tables I define are not created, and B) those that are appear to have the wrong name. I am wondering if this is due to how I defined my relationship (though it seems fine to me).

The tables in question are Memberships, Workouts, ExerciseGroups, and Exercises. The relationship being:
Membership 1 : N Workouts
Workouts 1 : N ExerciseGroups
ExerciseGroups 1 : N Exercises

So in essence it is a nested structure. My problem is that when I run the code, I see that I have a table called Exercise and Workout created, note that their names are supposed to be Exercises and Workouts, and I don't see my ExerciseGroups table created at all.

In my DataContext I define them as so:

```
public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
public DbSet<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
public DbSet<ExerciseGroup> ExerciseGroups { get; set; }
public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

builder.Entity<Membership>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Workouts)
            .WithOne(y => y.Membership);

builder.Entity<Workout>()
            .HasMany(x => x.ExerciseGroups)
            .WithOne(y => y.Workout);

builder.Entity<ExerciseGroup>()
            .HasMany(y => y.Exercises)
            .WithOne(x => x.ExerciseGroup);
```

Then for seeding the data I individuall seed each one using the Entity.HasData method.

The domain entities are defined as follows (I am only copying the relevant part that displays the relationship)

```
public class Membership {
     public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
}

public class Workout {
     public Membership Membership { get; set; }
     public string MembershipId { get; set; }
     public List<ExerciseGroup> ExerciseGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ExerciseGroup {
     public string WorkoutId { get; set; }
     public Workout Workout { get; set; }
     public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
}

public class Exercise {
     public string ExerciseGroupId { get; set; }
     public ExerciseGroup ExerciseGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a true answer, or if something is up with sqlite, but after I deleted all migrations, ensured that the migrations are pointing to the right ids when I seeded them (oddly one of the exercises just kept failing to add, no real explanation as to why), I now have the schema properly loaded.

I did change the Db set names to be singular instead of plural, to match the same naming style that I have in their individual domain classes. So Workouts -> Workout, etc.

I think I am just going to switch over to Mongo, doesn't have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

try to use virtual ICollection for navigation properties

You can design it in db and do scaffolding, i think it is easy way to understand how it work [about scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding)

```
public class Membership {
    public Membership ()
    {
        Workouts = new HashSet<Workout>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't scaffolding for situtations where you already have a DB schema predefined? In my case I am doing code first.

Comment: yes it is, but when i'm stuck with code first in beginning i just design it in db and scaffold into test project to see how it works

Comment: I see, that makes sense